# Why can't a round robin algorithm be used for jobs scheduling？

Tags: algorithm, process, dispatch

When I was studying job/process scheduling, I found that a round robin (RR) algorthm can not be used for jobs, only for processes.

I want to know why jobs scheduling can't use RR algorithms.

Comment: What's the difference between a job and a process? Do you mean "[round robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling)" rather than "round [rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_O._Rabin)"?

Comment: Yes, i mean "round robin". Job scheduling is like, when you click a software and then the software is copied from Hard Disk Drive to Memory. How much you clicked, how much jobs were dispatched. And process scheduling is that each program running in memory takes turns using the CPU. Thank for your answer.